# How not to repeat code using Bower and Gulp?

Tags: package, gulp, bower, dry, semantic-ui

I use Bower to manage front end packages on my project and Gulp to minify and create a single file with all CSS and JS from the packages. It saves that file on the `assets` folder, which is from where I get the files on html.

Right now, this is my `bower list`

```
├── cssfx#0.9.6
├── font-awesome#4.3.0
├── jquery#2.1.3
├─┬ jquery.cookie#1.4.1
│ └── jquery#2.1.3
├── jquery.ellipsis#0.7.1
├── normalize.css#3.0.3
└─┬ semantic-ui#1.12.0
  └── jquery#2.1.3
```

As you can see, I have `Semantic UI` and `normalize.css` installed. The problem is that `Semantic UI` uses `normalize.css` as reset, so the `normalize.css` is included in the `Semantic UI` code. On the css file generated by Gulp, the `normalize.css` is included twice, which is a problem because:

- The code is repeating, making the file bigger
- `Semantic UI` uses `normalize.css v3.0.1`, and the `normalize.css` installed with Bower is `v3.0.3`

---

This is the first time this happens to me, but let's say I use a package with includes another package that I already have installed, and the situation would be the same as above. So I believe the solution would have to be something that is valid to all packages.

Is there a way I could remove automatically the repeated code? In my case above, remove the `normalize.css` from `Semantic UI` and use the installed `normalize.css` package?

If this can't be done, the only way I could remove the repeated code is manually or there's another package manager like Bower or something like Gulp that has that feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a gulp task named gulp-minify-css that acts as a wrapper for clean-css:  https://github.com/jonathanepollack/gulp-minify-css

For grunt, the clean-css wrapper is named grunt-contrib-cssmin:  https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin

The underlying module (clean-css) is different from simple minification in that there are options to combine property declarations and eliminate declarations which are ultimately overridden by later ones.  I haven't tested myself, but I would imagine it would eliminate any redundancies in css which would be caused by the double inclusion of (almost) the same file.

However, this doesn't really address the problem.

In this case, you should just remove the standalone normalize.css.  If it included before Semantic UI, it will largely, if not entirely, be overridden by Semantic UI and its own copy of normalize.css. If it's included afterwards, then it is probably resetting things defined by Semantic UI, and you don't want that either.

Generally, if a framework includes normalize.css, it is intended to be used by itself with no other frameworks.  (i.e. You wouldn't use Foundation 5 and Semantic UI at the same time.)

When you concatenate your css, include any global frameworks first (Semantic UI) then add other things like icon packs, sliders (such as Slick.js), mobile navigation patterns (Slidebars.js), etc.

If you are using Semantic UI and you decide that Foundation (or some other framework) has a really nice feature that you want to use, you will often find that frameworks have CSS and JS broken down for individual components too.  Simply include the CSS file specific to the feature you are interested in.  In this case, there should be no duplicate code, although namespace conflicts are possible.

Also, if you're concerned about missing out on v3.0.3 of normalize.css because Semantic only has v3.0.1 included, I imagine there's hardly a difference.